# Mysql: Selecting values between two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, between

I'm trying to select a value between 2 columns. Here is my dataset

```
id    from    to    price
1     0.00    2.00  2.50
2     2.00    3.00  3.00
3     3.00    4.00  4.50
```

My goal, if I have a value of 2 is to select the line with the **ID 1** (between from and to). So here is the query I'm using :

```
select * from table where 2 between from and to;
```

And here are the results that MySQL returns when executing this query :

```
id    from    to    price
1     0.00    2.00  2.50
2     2.00    3.00  3.00
```

And the result I'm looking for is the following :

```
id    from    to    price
1     0.00    2.00  2.50
```

I've tried using < and >, etc. But, I'm always getting two results. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If your value is `2`, then the query matches it against the column `to` or `id`?

Comment: *My goal, if I have a value of 2 is to select the line with the ID 2* Your sample result has `ID=1`, which is it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

SO, you don't want the lower bound to be inclusive, right?

```
SET @value = 2;
SELECT * FROM table WHERE from > @value AND @value <= to;
```

Comment: I will tell you in plain english (easier). If my value is between from and to (inclusively for the column to), then I select the price. So, If I have a value of 2, the result must be the Id 1. If I have 2.001, the value must be Id 2.

Comment: @nblmedia but your data has a little problem: the lower boundary of record 2 is *exactly* equal to the upper boundary of record 1, so both intervals are included (I mean, 2 is both an element of [0,2] and of [2,3]). So, either define an open condition, like the one Vikdor proposes, or define intervals for which interceptions are really empty

Answer (score 36):

You could try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE 2 BETWEEN `from` AND `to`
```

Comment: I don't understand why this is getting down votes, it's a perfectly valid answer!

Comment: @tftd, it is getting down-voted because it is basically the same query that was already placed in the question. Also, this SQL query does not do what the question author asked to do.

Answer (score 9):

**Query 1:**

```
select * 
from `table` 
where `from` < 2 and `to` >= 2
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/716ea/1)

**Output:**

```
| ID | FROM | TO | PRICE |
--------------------------
|  1 |    0 |  2 |     3 |
```

**Query 2:**

```
select * 
from `table` 
where `from` < 2.001 and `to` >= 2.001
```

**Output:**

```
| ID | FROM | TO | PRICE |
--------------------------
|  2 |    2 |  3 |     3 |
```

Note: With this approach, you will get no rows back for value `0`, unless you modify the query to accommodate that.

Comment: Your first answer was correct : select * from table where 2 > from and 2 <= to. It works for the other values.

Comment: @nblmedia My two queries are identical. I just provided the output for your two data examples, `2` and `2.001`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this ,

```
select * from table where (from-to) = 2  // if you want the exact distance to be 2 
select * from table where (from-to) >= 2 // Distance more than 2
```